# Rust & GTK+3. How to create array containing a few elements of type glib::Value which can be casted to &[&ToValue] type?

Tags: gtk, rust, gtk3, glib, rust-gnome

I am creating GUI application using Rust and bindings for GTK+ 3 (called Gtk-rs or rust-gnome). I want to insert some data into `gtk::ListStore` (`GtkListStore`) using method [`insert_with_values`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.ListStore.html#method.insert_with_values)

**Working sample, but only one column:**
I can insert data if I have one column:

```
let type_of_a_column = &[gtk::Type::U32];
let data_for_column_1 = (2 as u32).to_value();
let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(type_of_a_column);
model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(None, &[0 as u32], &[&data_for_column_1]);
```

However I don't know how to hand over more data if I have more columns.
I know that internally it should call [gtk_list_store_insert_with_valuesv()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html#gtk-list-store-insert-with-valuesv)
so I need probably an array or slice, but if I do something like:

**Wanted to pass two elements in array, not working**

```
let type_of_a_column = &[gtk::Type::U32, gtk::Type::I64];
let data_for_column_1 = (2 as u32).to_value();
let data_for_column_2 = (4 as i64).to_value();
let array_of_data = [&data_for_column_1, &data_for_column_2];
let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(type_of_a_column);
model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(None, &[1 as u32], &[&array_of_data]);
```

it gives me during compilation:

> error: the trait bound `[&glib::Value; 2]: glib::IsA<glib::Object>` is
>   not satisfied [E0277]

and I don't know how to overcome it.

### **Not working MCVE**

### main.rs

```
extern crate gtk;

use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Box, ListStore, Orientation, TreeView, Window, WindowType};

fn exit_app() -> gtk::prelude::Inhibit {
    // Stop the main loop.
    gtk::main_quit();
    // Let the default handler destroy the window.
    Inhibit(false)
}

fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        panic!("Failed to initialize GTK.");
    }

    println!("Version of GTK+3:\t{}.{}",
             gtk::get_major_version(),
             gtk::get_minor_version());
    let window = Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel);
    window.set_title("Exercises with GtkTreeView and GtkListStore");
    window.set_position(gtk::WindowPosition::Center);
    window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| exit_app());

    let box_container = Box::new(Orientation::Vertical, 0);
    let view_list = TreeView::new();

    let types_inside_columns = &[gtk::Type::U32, gtk::Type::I64];
    let data_in_column_1 = (2 as u32).to_value();
    let data_in_column_2 = (4 as i64).to_value();

    let array_of_data = [&data_in_column_1, &data_in_column_2];

    let model_list_of_data = ListStore::new(types_inside_columns);

    model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(Some(0), &[0 as u32, 1 as u32], &[&array_of_data]);

    view_list.set_model(Some(&model_list_of_data));
    box_container.pack_start(&view_list, false, false, 0);
    window.add(&box_container);

    window.show_all();
    gtk::main();
}
```

### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test_of_gtk_3"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["wm_obsd"]

[dependencies.gtk]
version = "0.1.0"
features = ["v3_16"]

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

Comment: You also don't need to specify a `[[bin]]` section if your main file is `src/main.rs`, that's the conventional spot.

Comment: @Shepmaster
Changed to "&array_of_data", compiler complains:
`expected &[&gtk::ToValue],
    found &[&gtk::Value; 2]
(expected slice,
    found array of 2 elements)[E0308] `

---
Changed to "&array_of_data[..]", compiler complains:
`expected `&[&gtk::ToValue],
    found &[&gtk::Value]
(expected trait gtk::ToValue,
    found struct `gtk::Value`) [E0308]`


---
Changed to "&[&array_of_data[..]]", compiler complains:
`error: the trait bound `[&gtk::Value]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [E0277]
note: `[&gtk::Value]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time`

Comment: It successfully compiled :D

Comment: Note that `gtk::init().expect("Failed to initialize GTK");` is shorter **and** better — it prints the underlying error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, you are most likely to want to write something like this:

```
model_list_of_data.insert_with_values(Some(0), &[0, 1], &[&2u32, &4i64]);
```

Let's break down the function definition a bit:

```
fn insert_with_values(&self,
                      position: Option<u32>,
                      columns: &[u32],
                      values: &[&ToValue])
                      -> TreeIter;
```

This function takes an immutable reference to a `ListStore`, an optional position, zero-or-more columns as integers, and zero-or-more *references to the trait [`ToValue`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.ToValue.html)*.

What types implement `ToValue`? The documentation says:

```
impl<T> ToValue for Option<T> where T: SetValueOptional
impl<T> ToValue for T where T: SetValue + ?Sized
impl ToValue for Value
```

Taking a look at [`SetValue`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/value/trait.SetValue.html), we can see that it's implemented for the primitive integer types.

Since `u32` and `i64` implement `SetValue`, they also implement `ToValue`. A reference to the number can be implicitly coerced into a reference to the trait as well.

With this change, the window appears, but...

[image: blank window]

You'll have to figure out the mysteries of GTK from here!